# Rails validates uniqueness для PostgreSQL JSON type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Добрый день.
В PostgreSQL у меня есть таблица в которой есть поле type JSON
Как мне в модели сделать валидацию на уникальность этого поля?

Стандартная валицация в Rails `validates :info, presence: true, uniqueness: true`

Дает мне следующую ошибку:

```
PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: json = unknown
LINE 1: ... AS one FROM "telegrams" WHERE "telegrams"."info" = '{"Moved...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Стандартная валидация на уникальность из **Rails** тут не сработает. Не потому что не могут сделать нормально, а потому что **это в целом плохая идея.**

---

JSON сравнивать **очень ненадёжно**! Соответствие валидного JSON и валидных его составляющих не 1-к-1: можно большим количеством вариаций JSON представить одни и те же данные. Postgres хранит их практически "как есть" (текстом!), разве что выполняя валидацию и позволяя делать запросы по кусочкам значений.

*Разработчики PostgreSQL это понимали и `=` для `json`  **намеренно** не реализовали.* Rails к этой проблеме не имеет решительно никакого отношения.

Можно перейти на JSONB (в PostgreSQL 9.4 и выше), который запаковывает данные в более-менее нормализованный формат; оператор равенства для него **есть**.

---

Если это не вариант, остаётся только сравнение текстовых представлений.
**Скрестите пальцы и молитесь**, что алгоритм преобразования из Ruby-структур в JSON:

- **детерминированный**
  (не будет в зависимости от погоды на Марсе вставлять или не вставлять пробелы)
- **не изменится**
  (обновите библиотеку, и...)
- **будет единственным источником значений в этом поле**
  (работа с базой вручную или из других языков крайне не рекомендуется)

...ведь стоит забыть после запятой пробел, выйдет уже другой текст и база не откажется сохранять данные, даже если они там уже есть (например, `[1,2]` и `[1, 2]` **разные**).

Решение будет в духе:

```
validate do |x|
  if x.class.where('"telegrams"."info"::text = ?', x.info).exists?
    errors.add(:info, "Not unique")
  end
end
```

Но это только та часть, которая зависит от Rails.
**Но в базе будет то же самое,** вы даже *unique constraint* по этому полю не создадите без преобразований (потому что нет `=`!). А он нужен, иначе в результате race condition уникальность может внезапно нарушиться.

---

Ну и есть радикальный вариант: отказаться от `json` и нормализовать данные в `hstore`, массивы, столбцы, что угодно. Но обновление сервера БД, пожалуй, **менее** радикально.

---

Чтобы сократить число трюков с БД до минимума, можно всю ответственность за преобразования с JSON перегрузить на Ruby, в базе держать колонку типа `text`, а в модели прописать нечто такое:

```
serialize :info, JSON
```

Так, разумеется, вы потеряете возможность делать на уровне базы подвыборки изнутри JSON (без явных кастов а-ля `::json`, конечно) и потеряете гарантии базы на валидность загружаемого в неё JSON.

Comment: А нет ли гема, который бы мне помог в этом? так как смена версии PostgreSQL исключена

Comment: @МихаилЛуцко тогда всё очень, **очень** плохо. Обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, я сделал немного иначе, добавил в таблицу поле, в которое записываю некоторые значения которые определят уникальность моего json типа: `020-12345678/20FEB0853/1/2/@source` , и уже это поле проверяю на уникальность стандартным рельсовым валидатором, да это дублирование данных, но ничего страшного в этом нет. Хотелось бы узнать Ваше мнение по этому поводу

Comment: @МихаилЛуцко смотря что у вас в JSON'е, каких типов и насколько обязательно. Может иметь смысл, да.