# Rails 4.2.6 Проблемы с сохранением JSON поля Postgresql

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Есть Strong Parametrs:

```
params.require(:author).permit(:firstname, :secondname, :patronymic, :position, :data)
```

Поле data - имеет тип JSON, БД - PG

При сохранении/обновлении, поле остается пустым

Пробовал писать:

```
  props = params.require(:author).permit(:firstname, :secondname, :patronymic, :position, :data)
  props[:data] = params[:author][:data]
```

И так:

```
  props = params.require(:author).permit(:firstname, :secondname, :patronymic, :position, :data)
  props[:data] = params[:author][:data].to_hash
```

Пытается сделать ассоциацию и естественно ничего не получается.
Пробовал конвертацию в  json, но это строка все-таки:

```
  props = params.require(:author).permit(:firstname, :secondname, :patronymic, :position, :data)
  props[:data] = params[:author][:data].to_json
```

Ругается Postgres на тип данных.

Перебирать в контроллере - много и как-то неправильно. Но есть необходимость хранить данные, с динамическими полями и возможностью выборки по ним.

Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Такой вариант аналогичен:
      params.require(:author).permit( :firstname, :secondname, :patronymic, :position, data: { group: { } }  )

PG:
    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "data"
LINE 1: ...econdname" = $3 AND "authors"."position" = $4 AND "data"."gr...

Comment: Должно же как-то просто это решаться

Comment: params[:video].require(:author).permit( :firstname, :secondname, :patronymic, :position, data: []  )

Устанавливает значение по умолчанию

Comment: params[:video].require(:author).permit( :firstname, :secondname, :patronymic, :position, data: {}  )

Пишет пустой json

Comment: Вообще говоря, модель и БД тут немного ни при чём. Окей, вам надо пропустить что-то в ключе `:author`>`:data`. Кстати, что вы туда присылаете?

Comment: `Ругается Postgres на тип данных.` так а на что ругается? Ошибку в студию. А заодно, как поле в `db/schema.rb` определено?

Comment: t.json     "data",            default: {"debug"=>false}, null: false

Это schema.rb

Comment: А эта ошибка, если передать поле как to_json

1) Error:
AuthorsControllerTest#test_should_create_authors:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: json = unknown

LINE 1: ...ND "authors"."position" = $4 AND "authors"."data" = $5 LIMIT...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: О, ха-ха. Вы что, в тестах [ищете в базе по значению JSON](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/503916/181100)? Вдогонку, какая у вас версия PostgreSQL?

Comment: Стоп, я кажется понял... сейчас проверим

Comment: Да, метод find_and_create_by

Comment: Ну, это если игнорировать тот факт, что JSON-объекты не являются скалярами и Strong Parameters их as-is всё равно не пропустит :) Делать поиск в постгресе по полю типа `json` без дополнительных кастов нельзя.

Comment: create работает, а сравнение по json не работает, если память не изменяет

Comment: Затупил на ровном месте, благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Подобные случаи [числятся в гайдах, как "вне области Strong Parameters"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#outside-the-scope-of-strong-parameters).**

Если вы заранее знаете допустимые ключи со **скалярами** (одиночными значениями, коими хэшмапы и массивы *не являются*) во вложенном хэшмапе, то можете указать их явно:

```
params.require(:author)
      .permit(:firstname, :secondname, :patronymic, :position,
              data: [:one, :two, :three])
```

...а если нет, и вы хотите просто разрешать "всё что угодно", то Strong Parameters вам уже не помощник. Он придуман для типичных случаев, когда есть белый список ключей. Так что вам придётся подкручивать результаты его работы: делать выборку по ключам, которые вы знаете, а затем закидывать в него порции данных, ключи в которых вас не интересуют. Например, так:

```
author = params.require(:author)

author.permit(:firstname, :secondname, :patronymic, :position)
      .merge(author.slice(:data)) # <= "выщипывает" ключ-значение только для :data
#      ^^^^^ как обычный Hash#merge
```

---

*По мотивам комментариев:* помните, что для типа `json` оператора `=` не существует. Поэтому поиск по целому полю `data` работать не будет ни в `find_or_create`, [ни в `validates ..., :uniqueness`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/503916/rails-validates-uniqueness-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-postgresql-json-type), нигде. Он существует для `jsonb`, но это уже совсем другая история.